# GWT clickable link (anchor) without href

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to create a link (anchor) in GWT that can be clicked and it's `ClickEvent` can be processed, while at the same time this anchor wouldn't reload the page. This basically means that a `href` must not be set.

In javascript this is done like this:

```
<a href="javascript:handleAnchorClick();">Link</a>
```

or with

```
<a href="#" onclick="return handleAnchorClick()">Link</a>
```

where `handleAnchorClick()` returns false.

What would be the best way to achieve this in GWT?

Comment: If you set an href that starts with a `#` the page won't be reloaded, but the history stack will be changed, and you can respond to that event.

Comment: Exactly, the history stack is changed and I don't want to deal with that just to have a clickable link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use tha [Anchor element](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html#Anchor%28java.lang.String%29), and call its [addClickListener() method](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusWidget.html#addClickListener%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ClickListener%29) and add in what ever logic you wish. This sort of anchor doesn't reload the page.

Comment: Yes this seems to be the right way. Now I just need to find a way to use Anchor with this specific constructor in UiBinder.

Comment: Ah, simple. `@UiField(provided = true)` on the field.

Comment: ClickListener is depricated already ( I have the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387019/create-link-in-table-cell-and-open-float-popup-by-click-from-it).

Comment: Its hard when the api changes for an answer that was written in 2010.

Answer (score 10):

Listeners are deprecated in GWT use handlers

Something like that :

```
Anchor a = new Anchor("hi");
a.addClickhandler(new ClickHandler() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
           Window.alert("hi");
     }

});
```

Comment: AddClickhandler doesn't works, it must be "addClickHandler", Also forgot the closing brace, this code compiles:
    btnLogout.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Window.alert("hi");
        }
    });

Answer (score 8):

As you describe, using href="#" will reload the page.

This is what you can do in UIBinder:

```
    <g:Anchor ui:field="myScriptedAnchor" href="javascript:;">
        MyScriptedAnchorText
    </g:Anchor>
```

Then you can do whatever you want handling the ClickEvent in the view implementation.

```
    @UiHandler("myScriptedAnchor")
    void onMyScriptedAnchorClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // TODO whatever you want to do...
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget to add a style to anchor otherwise it doesnt behave like a normal html link:

```
.anchor {
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-weight: bold;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
        }
```